# dijit.FilteringSelect rich text label renders floats incorrectly?

Tags: label, dojo, css-float, dijit.form

I am using dijit's FilteringSelect box and trying to create a custom rich text HTML label, as per the documentation on dojocampus. I want my label to have the name of the object aligned to the left and a count aligned to the right. The way I am doing this is setting my label like so:

```
label: "left3 <span style=\"float:right;margin-top:-18px;\">right3</span>"
```

The problem is that when I hit the drop down menu, the right floated text appears about 20px below its associated left text. You can see an example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/j9c3n/  The first FilteringSelect box contains the "buggy" behavior, the second box is my current workaround (adding `margin-top:-18px`) to the label.

Is this the correct behavior for the FilteringSelect label? Am I doing something wrong with the HTML? I tried including a `<br style="clear:all;">` but that didn't help. I also tried setting all margins and padding to zero, as well as including a wrapper div around both the left and right text.  All I can think of is that maybe the problem is the line height?

I guess my question is, Is this a bug in dijit.FilteringSelect, or am I just wrong thinking that the labels should all be vertically aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
label: "<span style=\"float:right;margin-top:-18px;\">right3</span>left3 "
```

Comment: Hey, that works. I removed the margin-top: part to make them vertically align and I don't see any issues. Thanks!!

Comment: Hmm, spoke too soon. The small problem I see is that when you select an item, the dijit doesn't respect the float; so the selected item will look like: right3left3. Maybe I can use the labelFunc function to rewrite the label when it's selected.....thanks for your help though, it's a must better improvement over the margin-top:-18px;